# Why two different methods give two different answers to prove that $u=x^3-3xy^2$ is a harmonic function and find its harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Given function:
$u=x^3-3xy^2$.

I have solved this problem in two different methods, but two methods give two different answer. Why?

Here these are:
  $u_x=3x^2-3y^2, u_y=-6xy\\
u_{xx}=6x, u_{yy}=-6x$

So, $\nabla^2 u=0\implies u$ is harmonic function.

Let $v$ be conjugate harmonic function. Then it satisfies C-R equations:

$u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$

**method 1:**

$dv=v_x dx+ v_y dy\\
=-u_y dx+ u_x dy\\
=6xy dx+ (3x^2-3y^2) dy\\
v=3x^2y+(3x^2y-y^3)+c\\
v=6x^2y-y^3+c$

**method 2:**

$u_x=3x^2-3y^2\\
\implies v_y=3x^2-3y^2\\
\implies v=3x^2y-y^3+\phi(x)\\
\implies v_x=6xy+\phi'(x)\\
\implies -u_y= 6xy+\phi'(x)\\
\implies 6xy= 6xy+\phi'(x)\\
\implies    \phi'(x)=0\\
\implies \phi(x)=c $.
So, $v= 3x^2y-y^3+c$.
Above two methods give two different functions $v$, why? But two methods should give same $v$. Please help

Comment: In method $1$, that's not how you go from $dv$ to $v$.

Comment: @mercio thank you, I have got my mistake